# Stacked label with parentheses and exclusion

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser

I'm doing some labeling and have my labels stacked using python by using the following: [field1] + 'n\' + [field2]. But I'd like to keep the label stacked and add parentheses to [field2] as well as ">= 1". I tried using the following with little success. So really I don't know how to combine everything correctly to get it to work properly.

```
def FindLabel ( [field1], [field2] ):
  if long([field2]) >= 1:
    return "[field1] + '\n' + [field2]"
  else:
    return [field1]
```

Ideally, I want my label to look like this:

```
Field1
(field2).
```

---

Got it to work besides the parentheses. I would still like to add them if possible.

def FindLabel ( [NAME], [Deaths] ):
 if long([Deaths]) >=1:
  return [NAME] + '\n' +  [Deaths]

Comment: where does the >=1 fit in? is it a test or do you want it in the label

Comment: I would like to label only features that have a value for field2 that is >=1. I wasn't really too sure where to insert that.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
def FindLabel ( [field1], [field2] ):
  if long([field2]) >= 1:
    return [field1] + "\n" + "(" + [field2] + ")"
  else:
    return [field1]
```

Comment: Actually, you don't even need to use the Advanced code block: `"{}\n({})".format([field1] , [field2]) if long([field2]) >= 1 else [field1]`